# Why C-forkbombs don't work like bash ones?

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, fork

If I run the classical bash forkbomb:

```
:(){ :&:&};:
```

my system *hangs* after a few seconds.

I tried to write a forkbomb in C, here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main( )
{
    while(1) {
        fork();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it the system gets less responsive, but I can kill that process (even after minutes) just pressing `^C`.

---

The above code is different from the original bash forkbomb I posted: it's something more like:

```
:( )
{
    while true
    do
        :
    done
}
```

(I didn't test it; don't know if it'd *hang* the system).

So I also tried to implement the original version; here the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

inline void colon( const char *path )
{
    pid_t pid = fork( );
    if( pid == 0 ) {
        execl( path, path, 0 );
    }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    colon( argv[0] );
    colon( argv[0] );
    return 0;
}
```

But still nothing: I can run it and then easily kill it. It's not *hanging* my system.

---

Why?

What's so special about bash forkbombs? Is it because bash uses a lot more memory/CPU? Because bash processes call a lot more system calls (eg, to access filesystem) than mine?

Comment: As the saying goes, scientific breakthroughs are rarely accompanied by "Eureka!", commonly accompanied by "Hmm, that's odd."

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That C program is *tiny*, seriously tiny. In addition, fork()'ing a program like that is very, very efficient.  An interpreter, such as Bash, however, is much more expensive in terms of RAM usage, and needs to access the disk all the time.

Try running it for much longer. :)

Comment: Also, modern Unixes tend to use copy-on-write for virtual memory.  Unless each process actually writes to a memory location, they will all be using the same physical pages, even after the `exec`.  Put a few random mallocs in and writing to the malloced memory.  I think that will kill the machine.

Comment: Yes, I already cited these things, but which ones of them are the ones that hang the system and why? If for any process I spawn, I allocate 1MB of memory on the heap/stack, will it hang my system? Or if any process does 1 second of intensive calculation? Or if any process calls some system calls?

Comment: @peoro:  Technically you didn't.  My point wasn't that each new process uses little memory but that it actually uses no extra memory (apart from kernel structures). When you do a fork, the child process uses exactly the same physical pages as the parent until it writes something into memory.  Even with exec, the executable image is shared.  A new stack page will be created, but the big performance killer is swapping and this isn't going to happen unless you do some writes.

Comment: Add a couple `malloc`'s and write into what you allocate after the `fork()`.

Comment: No, this is not the real cause for such behavior. Here's what is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19322116/585725

Comment: @Arafangion What's efficient forking?

Comment: @SudipBhandari: I'm not sure what you mean?  I could give you the dictionary definition from google: "(of a system or machine) achieving maximum productivity with minimum wasted effort or expense."

Comment: @Arafangion in the context of a process forking another process what is efficient, resource, processsing, etc? OP's case doesn't consume much being a simple program.. Can you hint me about a program which does a significant amount of work and yet due to 'efficient forking' doesn't eat much compute resource?

Comment: @SudipBhandari: You're reading too much into the answer.  However, to answer your question, a tiny program implemented in C, without a garbage collector, on an operating system that implements COW pages (Copy On Write), as most linux systems do, will incur very little overhead.  Another process that takes several GB's of memory, will still fork efficiently on such a system as the memory isn't copied until it's modified.  This isn't the case on windows or programs that have a mark and sweep (or similar) GC.  But the C program shown was the simplest possible scenario, which will be efficient.

Answer (score 4):

The *real* cause for this is that in BASH the process you create is detached from the parent. If the parent process (the one you initially started) is killed, the rest of the processes live on. But in the C implementations you listed the child processes die if the parent is killed, so it's enough to bring down the initial process you started to bring down the *whole* tree of ever-forking processes.

I have not yet come up with a C forkbomb implementation that detaches child processes so that they're not killed if the parent dies. Links to such implementations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In your bash forkbomb, you are putting new processes in new background process groups, so you are not going to be able to `^C` them.

Answer (score 0):

Thats basically because of the size.
When you are running the bash fork bomb it loads  big monster programs into memory (with respect to your c program) each of them start hogging on your cpu resources.Definitely when big monsters start reproducing trouble comes more quickly than if bees start doing the same.
So the computer hangs immediately.However if you keep your c executable running for long it will hang the system too.Just that the time will be much much more.
If you want to compare the size of bash with size of c program check out /proc//status.
first with pid of any running instance of bash,and then with pid of any running instance of a c program